# Parse Server Javascript API Post To Pointer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a pointer field in my class on my Parse Server.  I am trying to use the Javascript API to write the objectId of a linked class field in a Pointer.  Here is my function:

```
  $scope.createItem = function (user, product) {
        var Item = Parse.Object.extend("II"),newII = new Item();
        newII.set("product", product);
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
        acl.setReadAccess(Parse.User.current(), true);
        acl.setWriteAccess(Parse.User.current(), true);
        // This doesn't work
        newII.set({
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "shop": "dklJ4Oaf2B"
        });
        newII.set("QTY", $scope.qtyCount);
        newII.save();
};
```

The ACL & QTY fields (number) write to the database without issue, however the pointer field (named "shop") doesn't populate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't 'hand' code what you think a pointer should look like, use the sdk to do it for you!

```
var shop = new ParseObject('Shop');
shop.id = 'dklJ4Oaf2B';
var newII = new Item();
newII.set('shop', shop);
newII.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 
    `newII.set('shop', new 
    Parse.Object('shop').createWithoutData('dklJ4Oaf2B');`
http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#data-types